# Python multiprocessing.pool failed to stop after finishing all the tasks

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have implemented a parser like this,

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def foo(i):
    try:
        # some codes
    except Exception, e:
        print e

def worker(i):
    foo(i)
    time.sleep(i)
    return i


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.map_async(worker, range(15))
    while not result.ready():
        print("num left: {}".format(result._number_left))
        time.sleep(1)
    real_result = result.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

My parser actually finishes all the processes but the results are not available ie, it's still inside the while loop and printing `num left : 2`. How I stop this? And I don't want the value of `real_result` variable.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7

Corresponding part of my code looks like,

```
    async_args = ((date, kw_dict) for date in dates)
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    no_rec = []

    def check_for_exit(msg):
        print msg
        if last_date in msg:
            print 'Terminating the pool'
            pool.terminate()
    try:
        result = pool.map_async(parse_date_range, async_args)
        while not result.ready():
            print("num left: {}".format(result._number_left))
            sleep(1)

        real_result = result.get(5)

        passed_dates = []

        for x, y in real_result:
            passed_dates.append(x)
            if y:
                no_rec.append(y[0])

        # if last_date in passed_dates:
        #     print 'Terminating the pool'
        #     pool.terminate()

        pool.close()
    except:

        print 'Pool error'
        pool.terminate()
        print traceback.format_exc()
    finally:
        pool.join()
```

Comment: Which version of Python on which OS?  Worked fine 5 times in a row for me, under Python 3.5.2 on 64-bit Win 10.

Comment: @TimPeters it works for small amount of data but while processing on large data sets, result.ready() won't return true after processing all the data.. ie, it stiill prints numleft 3: it remains for 15 mins then it prints numleft 2..

Comment: is this because of some worker process is still pending for output? worker func contains the code which also responsible for throwing exception but I properly used an except class to catch exceptions occured  inside that particular func.

Comment: I think you'll have to post an example that actually fails for other people.  For the heck of it, I removed the `sleep()` in the worker and boosted the input to `range(50000)`, and it still worked fine (under 3.5.2 and 2.7.11).

Comment: Is that I have to reduce the number of processes?

Comment: Since you haven't posted code that fails for me (or apparently for you either!), I have no way to guess what the problem might be in whatever code it is you're running that _does_ fail for you.

Comment: added .....................

Comment: It could be the worker has a bug that causes it to accumulate resources. An errant global collection intermediate data or something. When you create the pool you could add `maxtasksperchild=1` to see if the problem goes away. Thats a hint for the type of bug.

Comment: It could be that some tasks take much longer than others and you just have some workers who've had very bad luck and are putting in a lot of overtime. In the map call, you could set `chunksize=1` to see if everything evens up. Check CPU usage of the child processes while you are at it.

Comment: @tdelaney one of my worker function results in an exception.. Is this the reason for the pending workers? If so, then how would I tell the worker to stop after an exception is raised instead of waiting for result?

Comment: @TimPeters updated..

Comment: The `Pool`'s various `map` methods are patterned on the python `map` global function which terminates with an error if any of its iterations fails. For `map_async`, when an exception is raised, `result.ready()` should return positive even though the workers are still processing and `result._number_left` is > 0. `result.get()` should reraise the exception (but children are still working). And then `pool.close()` should wait until the children complete.

Comment: short answer: if you want to continue calculating the map, catch the exception in the child and supress it by returning a None or something. Logging it would be a good idea, though! This kinda subverts the idea of `map` which wants to error and quit so its a bit hackish.

Comment: @tdelaney is there any way to find which worker is hanging? I'm gonna set bounty for this question.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you have faulty `parse_date_range`,
which causes a worker process to terminate without producing any result or py exception.
Probably libc's  `exit` is called by a C module/lib due to a realy nasty error.
This code reproduces the infinite loop you observe:

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
import time

def parse_date_range(i):
    if i == 5:
        sys.exit(1) # or raise SystemExit; 
                    # other exceptions are handled by the pool
    time.sleep(i/19.)
    return i


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    result = pool.map_async(parse_date_range, range(15))
    while not result.ready():
        print("num left: {}".format(result._number_left))
        time.sleep(1)
    real_result = result.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Hope this'll help.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617545/python-multiprocessing-pool-failed-to-stop-after-finishing-all-the-tasks#comment68611587_40617545